# Query regarding jQuery datagrids

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid

I have been looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations)

I am looking for a datagrid jQuery plugin that will allow for the ability to edit a table of data by column.

For example each row in the table might need to contain the same specific string of data in one column. Instead of activley going one by one down the rows adding it in. Do any of the datagrid that you have used to allow this to happen in one go, such as a "Copy to all rows" function?

Thanks

Comment: this would be a custom code. It could be written using the JQgrid plugin in the `onSelectRow` or other table cell related events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was JQGris like Pawan, said